# Schematic input does not validate against the Schema on angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

While generating navigation component on angular 6 I got following error, how can I resolve it.

```
ng generate @angular/material:material-nav
```

> Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"inlineStyle":false,"inli                                         neTemplate":false,"changeDetection":"Default","styleext":"css","spec":true,"flat                                         ":false,"skipImport":false,"export":false}
>   Errors:
>
> Data path "" should have required property 'name'.

Comment: Try adding a name for the component: `ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name <component-name>`

Comment: @Und3rTow worked fine. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found command `ng generate @angular/material:nav <component-name>` on https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics but it doesn't work ...

@Und3rTow your response is perfect. running `ng generate @angular/material:nav --name <component-name>` works fine !!

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar error while generating a component, below worked for me `ng g c --name componentname`

Answer (score -1):

Keep on mind that all generated artifacts should have the name.
Similar like `ng generate component contact`